# How to fully display text in a multiturn prompt in Azure bot service chat integrated in Facebook Messenger?

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding, azure-cognitive-services, azure-bot-service, azure-appservice

I have built a bot in the Azure portal that functions as a replacement (help) for the FAQ of my website. I chose to also integrate the bot in Facebook messenger chat and to implement this messenger chat button on my website.

The problem now is that the multiturn prompts that I added into the knowledge base, don't display the full text of the questions that I am proposing to my users (see picture). If you click on one of the options though, the bot understands the question and reacts correspondingly.

How can I display these prompts 'fully'?

Thanks a lot! [This is what the chat bot looks like on my website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRMh0.png)

Comment: How are you choosing to display the multiturn prompts text? Are you sending via a hero card, Facebook quick reply, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

The integration of multiturn prompt chatbot in Facebook messenger is a great task, the issue which is caused due to the **`SDK issue`**. In general, if you follow the steps to create multiturn prompt chatbot with the process mentioned in the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/cognitive-services/QnAMaker/how-to/multi-turn), the default full text will be displayed. As it is an SDK issue, raise the issue with the [community](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues).